# OptaPlanner Best Practices for handling a requirement for calculations to determine a boolean return value

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner, kie

Consider the cloud computer example. What if the problem set has just been altered just a tad, so it changes the overall equation like this:

Suppose one of the requirements (say memory requirement) just had to return a boolean true or false if the processes memory requirement would fit on that cloud computers stock memory allocation or not.

But in order to do so - it first had to perform some java calculations to come up with that determination - like examine values in an array in some way.

What are the OptaPlanner best practices for (a) handling the boolean return value (it fits or not) and (b) handling the requirement to perform some java calculations to determine the boolean return value?

I could be a lot more specific, but I not muddy the waters until required to do so ...

Answer (score 0):

this is valid:

```
@PlanningEntity class MyEntity {

    private MyValue var;

    @PlanningEntity
    public MyValue getVar() {...}


    // Smart getters
    public boolean isVarCool {
        return var != null && var.isCool();
    }
    public boolean isVarCoolAndalive {
        return var != null && var.isCool() && var.isAlive(); 
    }
    public int getVarWeight {
        return var == null ? 0 : var.getAge() * this.getSomethingElse();
    }

}
```

And then use that in a constraint:

```
 rule x when MyEntity(varCool = false) then ... end

 rule y when MyEntity(varWeight > 10) then ... end
```